# TestNG classes to run all the time and parallel

Tags: junit, jenkins, testng

I want to run testNG classes to run all the time and parallel. What I mean is until I finish the execution of the test from Jenkins I want my tests to run all the time. And testclasses should run in parallel. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "until I finish the execution of test from jenkins"?  do you mean you kill the build?

Comment: I will run these tests in jenkins. So until the user abort the build I want these tests to run continuously. There can be 2 options. One is running each test project parallel continously. OR running whole testng project again and again

Comment: If you abort the build in between, there will be no results generated.  Why can't you just keep the recurrence of your build to say 5 mins, so that as soon as one build finishes, the next would get kicked in?  Parallel execution is definitely possible with testng

Comment: I am already doing continously builds but my customer does not want this. He wants to have one build which has test running continuously inside by reporting the test results. Is this possible

Comment: Everything's possible :)  But the effort should have reason.  I would also like to hear the rationale on why "the customer" wants this :)  How are you currently reporting results..writing to a db? to html? to excel?

Comment: We are writing the outputs as a surefire reports. They directly see at in the jenkins. They said it is not logical rebuild the jobs. Instead I should run the job one time which run the tests again and again

Comment: The current approach of reporting won't work then.  Surefire reports are essentially testng reports, which get generated at the end.  You would need to implement runtime reporting.  Possible options i can think of are implementing iresultlistener to generate runtime reports or writing to a db and giving a ui to your client ..

Comment: But we come to the totally different discussion. Can we run the test continously and how?

Comment: Set invocationcount of all your tests to a huge huge number.  i would never do that though :)

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you can't because it is not designed that way. It's not designed that way because in spite of you clients wish it is not logical to do so. What you can do is set Jenkins to build and run the test profiles when someone checks in code to trunk and then again every few hours on a cycle. There is no value to running tests in a continuous loop. You can also create branch builds for certain feature branches, these are useful as well for immediate feedback to devs before they merge back to trunk.

You can run your tests concurrently, if they don't share state (Which, they shouldn't). Assuming you are using Maven. If you want your tests to execute in a highly parallel fashion you can configure your Maven Surefire plugin to [Fork and Execute Parallel Tests.](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) Or, if you are using [Gradle set options.fork](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) accordingly